# Difference between DataStructure and DataModel - with example?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

If i want to load huge data and display in tableview , will create an DataModel Class - make a connection to server and update to coredata and fetch from coredata to the tableview .

Here where is this DataStructure concept comes . What is the Difference between DataStructure and DataModel . How to think about these two when creating an APP.

Thanks,
Dinesh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A **data model** is the data basis for an application, it represents the fundamental **concepts** that are relevant to the app. In object-oriented programming, these concepts are represented by **classes**, e.g. in a contacts application you might have a class *Person* that represents person objects within the application. This *person* class can have **attributes** such as *name*, or *phone number*. The **combination of these classes** forms your **data model**, as they *encapsulate* the data that will be used by your application.

A **data structure** is a more technical and lower-level term. Any sorts of data needs to be represented internally to the computer, this is by means of data structures. For example, an *array* is a data structure, as well as *dictionaries*. Also, the *classes* that form your data model, are **data structures** too, any representation of a specific data object has to be in form of a **data structure**. In iOS, classes are no more than wrappers on *structs* of the *C* programming language, so they are a very generic data structure that can be defined by the user.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Nikolas, Helps me alot ..Thanks for reply .

Comment: So If I have understood correctly, in my eCommerce app, if there are multiple classes to represent cart, user, items, and overall data behind their abstraction of name, it can be called a data model. In contrast, data structures are the underlying data organization that a class uses, organized based on the attribute a class is carrying. A user data model carries user information, which consists of arrays(data structure) of items he/she will purchase and a dictionary(data structure) of details about the user. Is it? Or am I making some fundamental mistake here?